# Return two consective rows with different conditions to satisfy

Tags: r

So I have a data that I want to pick consecutive rows,in which  the first row need to match condition 1 and the next one followed it also need match another conditions.

suppose I have a matrix A, I want to pick rows that column 1 is 0 and column 2 is in (24, 25) and successive row need be 1 for first column. So in my data below only row (2,3) and row(5,6) will be pick together.  row 4 satisfy condition 1 but has no following rows so it has abandoned.

```
A <- structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 22, 24, 1, 24, 25, 3), .Dim = c(6L,2L))
```

I expect output

```
 B <- structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 24, 1, 25, 3), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))
```

I haven't found a good way to solve it, hope any one can provide some suggestions. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can first find indices where column 1 is 0 and column 2 is in `c(24, 25)`, find out next rows where column 1 is 1 and filter those rows.

```
inds <- which(A[, 1] == 0 & A[, 2] %in% c(24, 25))
inds1 <- A[inds + 1, 1] == 1

A[sort(c(inds[inds1], (inds + 1)[inds1])), ]

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0   24
#[2,]    1    1
#[3,]    0   25
#[4,]    1    3
```

---

Approach using `dplyr`, `lead` and `slice`

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(A) %>%
      slice({
         inds = which(X1 == 0 & X2 %in% c(24, 25) & lead(X1) == 1)
         sort(c(inds, inds + 1))
        })

#  X1 X2
#1  0 24
#2  1  1
#3  0 25
#4  1  3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```r
ind <- A[,1] == 0 & A[,2] %in% c(24, 25) & c(A[-1,1] == 1, FALSE)
ind
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
A[ind,]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0   24
# [2,]    0   25
A[ind | c(FALSE, ind[-nrow(A)]), ]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0   24
# [2,]    1    1
# [3,]    0   25
# [4,]    1    3
```

Alternatively,

```r
A[sort(c(which(ind), which(ind) + 1)),]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0   24
# [2,]    1    1
# [3,]    0   25
# [4,]    1    3
```